# What could be the reason for a coefficient's change in magnitute and/or sign for identical specifications of OLS and Random Intercept Models?

Tags: mixed-model, least-squares

What could be the reason(s) for a coefficient's change in magnitute and/or sign for identical specifications of OLS and Random Intercept Models?

Further, does the Random Intercept Model, controlling for differences in the intercepts of each group, produce better estimates of the common fixed effects compared to its specular OLS?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

Imagine a dataset in which information about students distributed accross different schools have been collected.

You want to estimate the following model where `_i` indicates a variable which varies accross students, and `_j` accross schools, and thus to each student of the same school is attached the same value.

OLS: `math_i = beta0 + beta1* science_i + beta2* school_quality_j + e`

In the OLS setting above you cannot include factors for schools since they would be perfectly collinear with school_quality.

A solution would be using a random intercept model for which I can account for both the school_quality and other unobserved schools' characterics, the variation of which would end up in the random intercept.

Finally, if what I wrote above makes sense to you, how should I (or should not) compare the mixed model setting to the OLS?
For this last part suppose that the school_quality coefficient changes sign or magnitude.

Comment: What do you mean by "identical specifications"? Are the random effects from the random intercept model represented as fixed effects in the OLS model, or are they excluded?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example ?. If you don't include the factor as a fixed effect in `lm()`, then you could get Simpson's paradox. Otherwise they should be the same, compare the coefficient and SE of `Days` in: `lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)` with `lm(Reaction ~ Days + Subject, sleepstudy)
`

Comment: Let's say that I have a dataset in which the variable on which I want to investigate the effect is a group  variable. Thus either I use the variable or the factors for the group.
Given that the null random intercept model signals an IIC of 0.32, and the coefficient's estimates differ between the OLS (no group factors) and the LME model, can I say that:
1) OLS may suffer of Simpson's Paradox
2) LME is a way better specification for my case

Comment: That is not a reproducible example which @Robert suggested. If your problem is too large to post here can you reduce it in size to one showing the same effect?

Comment: Further to @mdewey's comment please explain the context of the data because it is hard for me to understand how a grouping variable could be a variable of interest. If it is then it obviously should not be a random intercept - and if you include it as a fixed effect you shouldn't invoke Simpson. But without more detail and an example it is impossible to say much more.

Comment: Re: your edit, the factor for schools is an ID whereas school quality is  some variable that *varies* from school to school - why would they be perfectly collinear?

Comment: @RobertLong, actually you are right. So as you wrote before the two model would be identical. (I have just tried with my data).
But do you confirm that not using the factors in the OLS would be a mistake if including that information doubles the R2 (this is my case)?
Inflated coefficients from that bad specified model could have come out because of the Simpson's paradox?

Comment: Yes, If you have school-level variation, which it seems you do, then not including school ID either as a fixed effect or a random intercept is a mistake, and yes, Simpson's paradox would be my suspicion.

Comment: Is there a way to be sure that talking about Simpons's Paradox is the right thing?

Comment: Please post the model formula and outputs of both models, where you see the switching signs.